# I want to force uppercase on Html.LabelFor in MVC razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razorengine

I am using MVC Razor as my View engine. I want to force uppercase on `Html.LabelFor` I tried the following techniques but not working for me!!

Please help me some one!

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.YearID.ToString ().ToUpper())
```

Above code giving below error:
**Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.**

```
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.YearID).ToString().ToUpper()
```

Above code working but out put showing along with html code like this:

`<LABEL FOR="STUDENTENROLLPLANS_SCHOOLYEARID">`WHICH SCHOOL YEAR ARE YOUR ENROLLING FOR?`</LABEL>`

Comment: check my answer, it works

Answer (score 6):

You can add a [DisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the `YearID` property and give it a name already in uppercase

```
[Display(Name = "WHICH SCHOOL YEAR ARE YOUR ENROLLING FOR?")]
public int YearID { get; set; }
```

In this case every label for `YearID` will be in uppercase. If you want only for specific labels, create a CSS class and aplly it to the label:

```
.uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.YearID , new { @class = "uppercase"})
```

Answer (score 3):

`@Html.Encode(item.Employee_Name).ToUpper()`
this is work in my program. I can display all the letters as capital by this code

Comment: This does not address the question.  The issue is combining with the ToString method and the LabelFor attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If `@Html.LabelFor()` is the only thing you are looking for then this should work for you!

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.YearID, Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.YearID).ToString().ToUpper())
```

there is an overload for a display text. You can enter a plain text or use a helper. 
**Generated HTML**

```
<label for="YearID">WHICH SCHOOL YEAR ARE YOUR ENROLLING FOR?</label>
```

Comment: This did work on forcing uppercase however also made the text bold..?

Comment: @Jay because it generates a `label` tag. make sure there is no css style associated to it